# URL Auto-Redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I recently moved my main website into a new folder: 
The websites was in `www.example.com.` 
The website is now in `www.example.com/website`

My problem is that alot of the links in the old site were direct links (not relative) ie `www.example.com/documents/example.pdf`

This is a problem because the same pdf is now in `www.example.com/website/documents/example.pdf`

Is there a way to intercept requests going from `www.example.com/website` to `www.example.com/` and add the `/website/` part on?

Wondering if this can be accomplished with a .htaccess rule

Comment: and PDF that used to be in `www.example.com/website/example.pdf` is now moved to `www.example.com/website/website/example.pdf` right?

Comment: No the pdf what was in: www.example.com/documents/example.pdf is now in www.example.com/website/documents/example.pdf

Comment: @Qwe yes it is in Apache

Comment: What im trying to get out of is changing all the absolute links from www.example.com/* to www.example.com/website/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/website/
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com/website%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Small note: I suggest using 302 code for testing and when you are happy with results change it to 301 (where required, of course). The reason -- modern browsers do cache 301 redirects .. so it may work already, but you still may see cached result.